# userscript: I lost some JS?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I do not understand what's going on...
I have a simple userscript, that add couple DIVs, css styles and JS functions in the pages I visit
In particular, I have one DIV that trigger a JS function with a onClick listener - this function is a "toggle" function (display/hide an other DIV):

```
function togglegm(etat) {
 if (etat = 'on') {
    document.getElementById('greasemky').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('greasemkytoggle').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:return(false);" onClick="togglegm(\'off\');"></a>';
 } else if (etat = 'off') {
  document.getElementById('greasemky').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('greasemkytoggle').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:return(false);" onClick="togglegm(\'on\');"></a>';
 }
}
var script2 = d.createElement('script');
script2.appendChild(d.createTextNode(togglegm));
(d.body || d.head || d.documentElement).appendChild(script2);
```

The DIV "greasemkytoggle" only contains a link with a onClick that trigger "togglegm('on'), and my objective is that when togglegm(on) is executed, the innerHTML of this DIV becomes a trigger for togglegm(off).
Now the weird part... when I click on my DIV greasemkytoggle, the function togglegm(on) is perfectly executed (greasemky is displayed), and the innerHTML is perfectly changed with a link for "togglegm(off)", BUT if I click again, then nothing happens.

I looked at the source code, and discovered that my JS function just disappeared (that's why nothing happened on the last click)! Now, there is an empty function replacing my togglegm():

```
<script>
scriptHolderArray1
</script>
```

Do you understand that kind of behaviour...?
I found nothing online for that kind of situation...

Comment: Those last three lines - what are they supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you all, I find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

GreaseMonkey runs under a much more security conscience set of rules.

Attach the event listeners using the proper DOM3 (addEventListener) method.

It is never a good idea (in user scripts *or* general scripting) to assign Javascript through innerHTML.

It is never a good idea to use the "javascript:" pseudo-protocol.

Comment: Thank Jeremy, you gave my an idea... I will try an other solution

Answer (score 0):

The problems are `etat = 'on'` and `etat = 'off'`.

If you want to set values, use

```
etat = 'on'
etat = 'off'
```

If you want to compare, use:

```
etat == 'on'
etat == 'off'
```

Moreover, `href="javascript:return(false);"` throws an error on Firefox because there is a return outside a function (SyntaxError: return not in function). You should do `href="javascript:void(0);"`, or `return false` at the end of the onclick event.

Anyway, I don't understand very well what you are doing here:

```
var script2 = d.createElement('script');
script2.appendChild(d.createTextNode(togglegm));
(d.body || d.head || d.documentElement).appendChild(script2);
```

You have a function `togglegm` loaded to browser's memory by a `<script>` element.

Then, you create a new `<script>` with that function and append it to the document, in order to load it to browser's memory again (I guess).

Why?

Comment: in fact I write a function, and with the appendChild function I inject the function in the webpage

Comment: @jrm But why do you want to inject the function to the page if you have declared it before?